# I am trying to show a random div with setinterval()

Tags: javascript

I am getting -  Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'style' of null
when I try to run the following:

```
   <script type="text/javascript">
    function startRotation() {
        setInterval(resetAllDivs(), 20000);
    }
    function resetAllDivs(){
        var i;
        for(i=1; i<=15; i++) {
            document.getElementById("img"+i).style.display = "none";
        }

        displayRandom();
    }

    function displayRandom(){
        var n=Math.round(Math.random()*3)
        document.getElementById("img"+n).style.display = "block";
        document.getElementById("img"+n).style.width = "64%";
    }
</script>
```

I am calling startRotation() above my closing  using:

```
 document.addEventListener('DOMContentLoaded',function(){startRotation()});
```

The error points to the line:

```
 document.getElementById("img"+i).style.display = "none";
```

Any ideas?

Comment: Do you not have 15 imgs with ids img1-15 ?

Comment: @zfrisch, yes - except the ids are on divs containing the imgs

Comment: Note that you shouldn't call the function yourself, otherwise the `setInterval` effectively doesn't do anything. Pass the function itself without calling it.

Comment: @Vohuman, can you explain further? DO you mean I shouldn't call startRotation() on DOMContentLoaded?

Comment: @RogerCreasy No, I meant that line should be `setInterval(resetAllDivs, 20000);`

Comment: @RogerCreasy because some people don't understand the point of down voting.

Comment: Can you reproduce the error on http://jsfiddle.net?

Comment: @Vohuman I'll try to put it together on jsfiddle - may be a while. I maade the change you suggested - no difference. I changed the counter (i) to only 3. Now, I get Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected identifier on the line that starts my for loop.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A few things to note, some of them have be pointed out in the comments already, but I'll reiterate.

`setInterval` expects a function reference as its first parameter, you're passing in the return result of a call to `resetAllDivs()`, which is `undefined`. Really you've got

```
setInterval(undefined, 20000);
```

which won't work. You want

```
setInterval(resetAllDivs, 20000);
```

Next, this line will get you a random number between 0 - 3, which I don't think is what you were after. It's why you sometimes you'll try `document.getElementById('img0')`, which returns `null`.

```
 Math.round(Math.random()*3)
```

Instead, this will get you a number between 1 - 15:

```
Math.floor((Math.random() * 15) + 1);
```

Here is a working example. Timing reduced to half a second instead of 20.

<kbd>[**DEMO**](http://jsbin.com/butixi/1/edit?html,css,js,output)</kbd>

```js
function startRotation() {
  resetAllDivs();
  setInterval(resetAllDivs, 500);
}

function resetAllDivs(){
  for (var i = 1; i <= 15; i++) {
    document.getElementById("img" + i).style.display = "none";
  }

  displayRandom();
}

function displayRandom(){
  var n = Math.floor((Math.random() * 15) + 1);
  document.getElementById("img" + n).style.display = "block";
  document.getElementById("img" + n).style.width = "64%";
}

startRotation();
```

```css
div {
  width: 50px;
  height: 50px;
  
  background-color: red;
}

div:nth-child(even) {
  background-color: blue;
}
```

```html
<div id="img1"></div>
<div id="img2"></div>
<div id="img3"></div>
<div id="img4"></div>
<div id="img5"></div>
<div id="img6"></div>
<div id="img7"></div>
<div id="img8"></div>
<div id="img9"></div>
<div id="img10"></div>
<div id="img11"></div>
<div id="img12"></div>
<div id="img13"></div>
<div id="img14"></div>
<div id="img15"></div>
```

This code could definitely be refactored into something smarter. I'd also advise using [`setTimeout`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/WindowTimers/setTimeout) over [`setInterval`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/WindowTimers/setInterval), as you gain more control.

Comment: Thanks so much! Your code got me past the errors. I really appreciate the explanations, too!

Answer (score 0):

One of your `document.getElementById("img"+i)` is returning a null value, wich means that the element doesn't exist or wasn't created before your resetAllDvis() functions runs.

You should use:

`Math.floor((Math.random() * 15) + 1);`

to return a random number between 1 and 15.

Make sure you have images with id's from `id="img1"` to `id="img15"`.